# How should the logo of Magento.Stackexchange look like?

Tags: discussion

- Should and can we include the official Magento logo?
- Or something derived?
- Feel free to submit suggestions.

Comment: Had to be asked a while a go!

Answer (score 5):

My idea is that site  has to be named **mageoverflow** :) and logo can be something in between of SO and Magento. Like sliced Magento logo overflowing the SO logo box.

Comment: Seems better to stick with the "oops" theme... I like `flushed-cache` since that's pretty much step #1 in Magento debugging.

Answer (score 3):

We **need eBay branding** all over this site. **Settle down, I'm just kidding.**

Magento Orange is a **given** - but perhaps utilize the theme presented at the 2013 Imagine - triangles interlocking to form a mesh-like structure. I can see that across the masthead of the SE site.

The logo could be extended like they do for the hackathons - something protruding from the bottom of the Magento logo. Perhaps it could be forming an implicit question mark (perhaps upside down?), to reference the Q&A nature of the site.

As for the name, I like Magento.SE.

If we do the 'oops' sort of a theme - we need to reference reindexing or out of memory PHP errors.

Comment: if there were a Magento CoC in place I would *so* ban you for trolling