# Changing the website logo

Tags: discussion

I find that the current "MA" logo for magento.stackexchange is difficult to recognize, and to differentiate from other stackexchange "letters logos". (For example when I look at the list of "Hot Network Questions")

I searched a little on the meta, and only found [one thread about it](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-should-the-logo-of-magento-stackexchange-look-like), from February 2013 !

I think it could be a good thing to have a personalized appearance, to feel more "at home". But is it possible ? And what is your position about that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible yet in the limited beta graduation phase. We will not receive a custom site theme at this time.

Please [read the guidelines on our graduation](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/633/its-election-and-graduation-eve) and some information on [design-independent graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) - hopefully these two concepts will help you understand why we don't have a custom logo.

Comment: FYI: Website and logo discussion has been started within the ["Magento Site Design"](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/817/magento-site-design) thread.